Protocol for new tag suggestions and retagging

Are you guys n gals ok with me making more tag suggestions on here?
Also, also, are you guys n gals happy for me to apply new tags retrogradely to existing posts? 

ps pls note I have edit privileges now, so it won't choke up review queues


I would encourage you to edit particular questions. In particular, questions by new users rarely have correct tags applied. Thus, improving questions as they are posted, particularly by adding tags makes a lot of sense. Similarly there are often particular questions that you may stumble upon that were never really reviewed in the first place. Thus, fixing the tags and so on is a good strategy.
I would discourage mass retaggings. Generally, if a particular tag has not been applied to a set of questions, that often implies that users of the site don't want that tag applied to that set of questions. Thus, applying such a tag on mass may be against the wishes of site users; also, a minor consideration is that mass retagging  swamps the home page. 
That said, there are times where mass retaggings make sense. (1) we decide to introduce a new tag, and then want to retroactively apply it to a set of previous questions. (2) we make a decision that one tag is no longer needed, but should be replaced with another one. In both these cases, there would typically be a post on meta checking whether users of the site felt that it was a good idea.  

